# retrieving sql data in XML

Tags: mysql, xml, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

I have spring-security.xml file. In that I'm writing sql query to select records from database. Now I need to pass those records to servlet . Is it possible to do ? How ? Or any alternative ways to do it ??

This is my spring-security.xml

```
 <authentication-manager>  
   <authentication-provider>  
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select user_login_name,user_password,user_id,role_type_id from sox_audit.sox_users where user_login_name=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  "/>

    <!--  <user-service>  
  <user name="Sriram" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />  
  <user name="Vignesh" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /> 
  <user name="Yogesh" password="12345" authorities="PARTNER_CUSTOMER" /> 
     </user-service>   -->

   </authentication-provider>  
 </authentication-manager>
```